I want an android app to persist even after a factory reset. How do I do that?
I'm trying to make a corporate app persist on an android device (android 12 rooted), even after a factory reset. How would I go about doing that?
I had tried making the app a system app using systemizer on a rooted device, but upon factory reset the app got erased.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
